# Spyder does not release memory when re-running cells

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, spyder

Spyder's memory management is driving me crazy lately. I need to load large datasets (up to 10 GB) and preprocess them. Later on I perform some calculations / modelling (using sklearn) and plots on them. Spyder's cell functionality is perfect for this since it allows me to run the same calculations several times (using different parameters) without repeating the time-consuming preprocessing steps. However, I'm running into memory issues when repeatedly running cells for various reasons:

- Re-running the same cell various times increases the memory consumption. I don't understand this since I'm not introducing new variables and previous (global) variables should just be overwritten.
- Encapsulating variables in a function helps but not to the degree that one should expect. I have a strong feeling that the memory of local variables is often not released correctly (this also holds when returning any values with .copy() to avoid references to local variables).
- Large matplotlib objects do not get recycled properly. Running gc.collect() can help sometimes but does not always clear all the used memory from plots.
- When using the 'Clear all variables' button from the IPython console often only parts of the memory get released and several GBs of memory might still remain occupied.
- Running %reset from the IPython console works better but does not always clear the memory completely neither (even when running import gc; gc.collect() afterwards).
- The only thing that helps for sure is restarting the kernel. However, I don't like doing this since it removes all the output from the console.

Advice on any of the above points is appreciated, as well as some elaboration on the memory management of Spyder. I'm using multi-threading in my code and have a suspicion that some of the issues are related to that, even though I was not able to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Take a look at run->configuration per file. You can choose whether to run your script in a new empty console, or in the current one

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If you copy/paste your code in a Jupyter notebook, do you have the same problems?